# Installing Homebrew via shell script

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew

This must be an easy one.  I'd like to install Homebrew via a shell script on OS X.

Homebrew's recommended installation from the terminal works,

```
$ ruby <(curl -fsSk https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)
```

but if I put the following in a file *test.sh*,

```
#!/bin/sh
ruby <(curl -fsSk https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)
```

then execute it,

```
$ sh test.sh
```

I receive the following error:

```
test.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: line 2: `ruby <(curl -fsSk https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)'
```

What is the correct syntax to use in a shell script to get this to work and why is it different from the command line?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's complaining because `sh` doesn't have that syntax, but `bash` does. Use `#!/bin/bash` instead.

Also, no need to use the `sh` command to execute shell scripts (that's the whole point of putting the hashbang!). Just `chmod +x script.sh` and invoke with `./script.sh`

Answer (score 1):

When you run `bash` as `sh` it emulates `sh`, which has many fewer features than `bash` (including one you're trying to use here). Use `/bin/bash` instead.